# How to Authenticate Azure AD users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I want to authenticate the Active AD users in my application. Only authorized users should be able to login. My application components are

1. Web Page (Client)
2. Net Core API 6.0
3. Azure AD.

The Azure AD login credentials will be entered through the web client.
Please let me know if the following is the correct way to do the authentication.

Get the Token by connecting to Azure AD through the web client.
Send the token to web API for validation.

Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: You should use Azure AD as identity provider. Azure AD will do the authentication and issue Token which you can return to the client. Instead of web page collecting the username/password and pass to Azure AD, user should be redirected to Azure AD and let it take care of validating the username/password.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory

Comment: You can use MSAL libraries to handle the authentication for you. I don't know in which framework you are developing your Client, but you can check here all the MS samples for AAD, including several ones that fit your scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- We have reproduced authenticating AD Users in our environment, please check the below workaround.
- Created `.Net Core WebAPI 6.0` sample application, Published to Azure App Service.
- In `Azure Portal`, navigate to your `web app` => `Authentication` => `Add provider` under Identity provider.
  [image]

Click on `Add Identity Provider`, select `Microsoft` as an Identity Provider and Save.[image]

- After adding Identity provider, Navigate to Azure Active Directory, in `App registrations` section, check in the All applications- you can see the new app registration is available with the same name of your Web App.
- If it is not available add New Registration, click on  `Authentication` => Add a platform => Select Web and Add the Redirect URI.

[image]

***Redirect URI*** - `https://YourWebAppName.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`

- Try to access the published App, It will be navigated to the Microsoft Page.Once after authenticating the user it will be redirected to your WebApp.

[image]

***OutPut :***
[image]

[image]

***References taken from :***
[Configure App Service  to use Azure AD login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad)